# How to update nested subdocument by condition in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I have the following data structure:

```
// Journeys collection in MongoDB

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("560feabb682290c218770110"),
    "title" : "El Camino de Santiago",
    "messages" : [ 
        {
            "title" : "The sun is strong!",
            "text" : "Lorem ipsum and something more text goes here",
            "lat" : "-34.5555555",
            "lng" : "23.34455335",
            "_id" : ObjectId("560feabc682290c218770111")
        },
      {
            "title" : "The hike was great",
            "text" : "Lorem ipsum and something more text goes here",
            "lat" : "-34.5555555",
            "lng" : "23.34455335",
            "_id" : ObjectId("560feab9682290c21877010f")
        }
    ],
    "followers" : []
}
```

How do I make an update to the `title` field of the message with an `_id` of `560feab9682290c21877010f` in **this specific journey**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
db.journeys.update({'messages.id':  ObjectId("560feab9682290c21877010f")}, {$set: {'messages.$.title': 'New Title'}});
```